# Ruby on rails: Regex to include accented and specials characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app I want to use a regex that accept accented characters(é ç à, ...) and special characters(& () " ' , ...), right now this is my vlidation

```
validates_format_of :job_title, 
                      :with =>  /[a-zA-Z0-9]/, 
                      :message  => "le titre de l'offre n'est pas valide",
                      :multiline => true
```

i want also that regex to not accept non latin characters like Arabic, Chinese, ...

Comment: Put those special characters into your regex.

Comment: Is stuff like «, » or ¡ acceptable? Arbitrarily restricting characters is going to annoy a lot of people, especially when you've accidentally forgotten an accented character they need to use.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`[:alnum:]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) for alphanumeric characters:

```
validates_format_of :job_title, 
                  :with =>  /[[:alnum:]]/, 
                  :message  => "le titre de l'offre n'est pas valide",
                  :multiline => true
```

Comment: in this case Arabic, Chinese and others characters will be accepted

Answer (score 2):

For the Latin characters you could use the [`\p{Latin}` script character property](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties). You would have to make sure you [normalize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html#method-i-normalize) the input first, as decomposed strings won’t match (i.e. strings containing characters using combining characters). Also this wouldn’t match things like `x́` (that’s `x` followed by `COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT`) since it won’t compose into a single character, but that’s probably okay as it’s not likely to be actually used by anyone.

For the “special characters” you really need to be more specific about what you want. You say you want to allow `"` and `'` (so called “straight” quotes), but what about `“`, `”`, `‘` and `’` (“typographical” or “curly” quotes”). And since you are allowing European languages, what about `«`, `»`, `‹`, `›` and `„`? You could use the `\p{Punct}` class, which should match all these and more, you will need to decide if it matches too much.

You probably also want to match spaces as well. Will just the space character be okay? What about tabs, non-breaking spaces, newlines etc.? `\p{Space}` should get them.

There may be other characters you need to match that these won’t pick up, e.g. current symbols, may need to add those too.

So a first attempt at your regex might look like this (I’ve added `\A` and `\z` to anchor the start and end, as well as `*` to match all characters – I think you will need them):

```
/\A[\p{Latin}\p{Punct}\p{Space}0-9]*\z/
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to white-list all the characters you want to accept. For example:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ&*]/
```

Instead of `a-zA-Z0-9` you can use `\w`. It represents any word character (letter, number, underscore).

```
/[\wáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ&*]/
```

Comment: That's hardly an exhaustive list. There's dozens of others you'd need to include, like åàäâ for 'a' alone, and others like ç, ø or ß that might qualify. Honestly it might be easier to list the ASCII characters that are acceptable than to come up with a list of non-ASCII characters, right? ☃